# html weekly recipe table button

Tags: html, css

I need help I am trying to make a weekly recipe webpage with html and css. it has a form asking for the recipe you want to add when you hit the add button the recipe should be added into one of the weekdays that the user specified which should be a table showing all the recipes for a particular day can someone show me how I could do this please thank you below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Weekly Recipes </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="heading">
        <h2>Weekly Recipes</h2>
    <div>

    <form method="POST" action="index.html">
        <input type="text" name="task" class="task_input">
        <button type="submit" class="task_btn" name="submit">Add Recipe</button>

    </form>

    <div>
        <table id="t01">
          <tr>
            <th>Sunday</th>
            <th>Monday</th> 
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

css page

```
    .heading{
    width: 400px;
    height:150px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6B8E23;
    background: #FFF8DC;
    border: 2px solid #6B8E23;
    border-radius: 20px

}

form{
    width:250px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    border-radius :5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #FFF8DC;
    border: 1px solid #6B8E23;
}

table {
  width:100%;

}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #fff;
}
table#t01 th {
  background-color: #6B8E23;
  color: white;


}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: how can i use a button to add items to a table

Comment: Do you want to send those items off to be persisted with some sort of database technology? Do you want them to be stored locally in the client's browser?

Comment: @TomFaltesek as for right now i just want it to appear on the table

Comment: Let's say I type "Pizza" into your text input and press the "Add Recipe" button, where is that supposed to appear in your table? Underneath Friday? What if I type "Apple Pie"? Should that appear under Sunday? This question is unanswerable as it stands. It's way too open-ended.

Comment: @TomFaltesek i am trying to figure out a way to specify which day the recipe should go on what do you think i should do

Answer (score 1):

You will need JavaScript if you want to update the site live.
Try searching for w3schools on google, they provide a really good JavaScript-Tutorial.

If you want to send the form to server which saves the recipe and renders it to the page on reload, you can use PHP or some similar server side programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using minimal JavaScript to update the DOM according to the very few provided requirements.

```js
document.getElementById("recipe-form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Don't attempt to post form to server.

  const recipe = document.getElementById("task").value;
  const day = document.getElementById("day").value;
  const cell = document.querySelectorAll("#t01 td")[day];

  cell.innerHTML += "<p>" + recipe + "</p>"; // Update the chosen day cell.
  document.getElementById("task").value = null; // Clear the input.
});
```

```css
.heading {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6B8E23;
  background: #FFF8DC;
  border: 2px solid #6B8E23;
  border-radius: 20px
}

form {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFF8DC;
  border: 1px solid #6B8E23;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table#t01 th {
  background-color: #6B8E23;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <h2>Weekly Recipes</h2>
</div>

<form id="recipe-form">
  <input type="text" name="task" id="task" class="task_input">
  <select id="day">
    <option value="0">Sunday</option>
    <option value="1">Monday</option>
    <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="4">Thursday</option>
    <option value="5">Friday</option>
    <option value="6">Saturday</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="task_btn" name="submit">Add Recipe</button>

</form>

<div>
  <table id="t01">
    <tr>
      <th>Sunday</th>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
      <th>Saturday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```